# Android NumberPicker string values not fit

Tags: android, textview, numberpicker

a made a customNumberPicker:

```
public class CustomNumberPicker extends NumberPicker {

    public CustomNumberPicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void addView(View child) {
        super.addView(child);
        updateView(child);
    }

    @Override
    public void addView(View child, int index, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
        super.addView(child, index, params);
        updateView(child);
    }

    @Override
    public void addView(View child, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
        super.addView(child, params);
        updateView(child);
    }

    private void updateView(View view) {
        if (view instanceof TextView) {
            TextView tv = (TextView) view;
            tv.setLines(3);
            tv.setTextSize(16);
            tv.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            tv.setPadding(20, 10, 20, 10);
            tv.setMaxWidth(10);
            tv.setSingleLine(false);
            tv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            tv.requestLayout();
            tv.invalidate();
    }
        }

    }
}
```

i call it this way:
xml:

```
 <hu.enyim.pickerexample.CustomNumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/picker"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"/>
```

java:

```
 picker = (CustomNumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.picker);
        picker.setMinValue(0);
        picker.setMaxValue(values.length - 1);
        picker.setDisplayedValues(values);
```

but the long Text-s not fit to the screen.

[image]

i would like to make it work like multiLine.
please help me with this.
Thank you!

here is a video about it:
[video](https://youtu.be/x9KOGTcZVec)

Comment: And what is the expected result? Do you expect them to wrap content into several lines or to put "..." in the end or middle of each item?

Comment: yes i would like to make it work like multiLine.

Comment: What if you replace the last line of `updateView` method with `tv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));` ?

Comment: I would also try to change order of methods calls here `super.addView(child);         updateView(child);`

Comment: @foxanna nothing changed. but somethims if i click on an item it wrap the text in multilne,  but on change it revert the multiline

Comment: You can also try to call `tv.requestLayout()` or `tv.invalidate()` in the end of `updateView` method

Comment: @foxanna i have made all your changes what you tell me. nothing changes. please watch the video, edited the question

Comment: Do you get any solution??

Comment: @SachinVarma no, i have had to shorten the texts.

Comment: Ok, was trying to implement same.